# How to develop Einstein field equations for spherical symmetry space time?

Tags: riemannian-geometry, general-relativity, special-relativity

Spherical Symmetry Space Time is given by:

$ds^2$ = $e^\omega c^2dt^2$ -  $e^\eta dt^2$ + $d\theta^2$+ $\sin^2 d\phi^2$

where $\eta$ and $\omega$ are functions of r.

I have calculated all the Ricci tensor components, which are:

$R(00)$ = $\omega''$ + 1/2 $\omega'$($\omega'-\eta'$) - 2/r($\omega'$)

$R(11)$ = $\omega''$ + 1/2 $\omega'$($\omega'-\eta'$) - 2/r($\eta'$)

$R(22)$ = (-r(e^$-\eta))$ + $\csc^2 \theta$ + $(\eta'/2+\omega'/2 + 2/r)$($-r$e^$-\eta)$) + 2e(e^$-\omega))$ - $\cot^2\theta$

$R(33)$= $\sin^2\theta$($R(22)$)

How to develop Einstein Field equations for perfect fluid energy momentum tensor

and

How to find Anisotropic energy momentum tensor?